# Why I can't get this element identified by an id attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have this element, it is auto generated by mcssl checkout form. It is a custom field. I'm trying to select it using javascript like so:

```js
var form_field_gclid = document.getElementById("#ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox");; 
       console.log(form_field_gclid);
```

```html
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$scPageContent$customFieldsControl$customFieldsRepeater$ctl00$customFieldTextBox" type="text" maxlength="200" size="50" id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox" class="text">
```

But I'm getting `null` as a result. I've tried also, `document.querySelectorAll(...);` but the same result. It's working when I tried it from console but I'm wondering why it won't work if it's on page javascript. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

I tried getting rid of the # sign but same result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
   
  var form_field_test = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox");; 
   console.log(form_field_test);
}());
</script>
```

This is the full script I'm using.

Comment: Sounds like your javascript is running before the element is on the page.

Comment: Lose the `#` on the .getElementById().

Comment: Was the element loaded when you called the function? Try $(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ybh0r49u/2/

Comment: https://www.mcssl.com/SecureCart/Checkout.aspx?mid=B4CE0BB1-7972-4089-9524-045414B671C6&sctoken=6530e8f4f2fa471eb0d4d1be89f17148&bhjs=1&bhqs=1

this is the page, if you open the console, you'll see it printed 'null' and if you view the source it has the js script in place.

Comment: @tymeJV you might be right about that

Answer (score 5):

You do not need the `#` in your call to `document.getElementById`. Simply remove it.

```
var form_field_gclid = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox");
```

If you were using jQuery, however, you would need it:

```
var myElement = $('#myElementId');
```

But since you are using vanilla JS, simply pass in the element's `id` as a string.

Comment: the same result, null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the script below the html of the input you are trying to hook.
If the form is not rendered the script will return null.

In your webpage you run the script before the input form is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the input value. Right?

Also i added a button for you to give you an example about how to add more functionality. For example, how to add a background color to your input

```js
var form_field_gclid = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox").value; 
       console.log(form_field_gclid);
       // add color to your input
       function  addColor(){
             form_field_gclid =  document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox").style.backgroundColor  = "green";
       }
```

```html
If you mean to get the value of the input, i think you are looking for this:
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$scPageContent$customFieldsControl$customFieldsRepeater$ctl00$customFieldTextBox" type="text" maxlength="200" size="50" id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox" class="text" value="1">
<button onclick="addColor();">change color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this old school vanilla ::

```js
var form_field_gclid = ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox;

       console.log( form_field_gclid );
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="200" size="50" id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_customFieldsControl_customFieldsRepeater_ctl00_customFieldTextBox" class="text">
```